# Definition of An Infinite Sequence Being Random: Is the Infinite Monkey Theorem Sufficient?

Tags: sequences-and-series, random

I realize that by the Infinity Monkey Theorem, an infinite sequence of numbers from 0 to 9 chosen randomly will contain every finite subsequence. My question: is this sufficient for a precise definition of an infinite sequence being random? That is, let $a_{k}$ $k$ a positive integer, being a sequence of integers between $0$ and $9$ (e.g. digits of a real number). Can we *define* that that is sequence will be random if for and $n$, and for all finite sequences $b_{j}(n)$ of number from $0$ to $9$ of length $n$ ($j$ ranges from $1$ to $n$), there exists an $m$ such that $a_{m-1+j}=b_{j}(n)$ for all $j$ ranging from $1$ to $n$. That is, $a_{k}$ is *random* precisely when the infinite sequence contains EVERY possible subsequence of EVERY possible length. Would this be a sufficient definition of randomness? If so, is it the criterion on which the randomness of the digits of $\pi$ rest? And has this been proven?

Comment: You also need to include that different subsequences of the same length are equally probable.

Comment: I feel like this is tied somewhat to the definition of a normal number (which pi is conjectured to be, but it's not been proven).

Comment: Okay, but I was looking for a definition of randomness that would be precise. Is there a precise definition that different subsequences of the same length are equally probable that resorts to an equation that can be either proven or refuted and not a statistical test?

Answer (score 1):

This is the tip of an [alternative theory of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sequence) which seems to have been formulated first by Richard von Mises, elaborated by Alonzo Church, and more recently by others, as listed in the cited Wikipedia article.  See also [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/chance-randomness/) for an extended discussion.

This approach has had its ups and downs.  Most mathematicians have, I think, rejected it in favor of the measure-theoretical formulation associated with Borel and Kolmogorov, at least as a useful starting point for day-to-day work. But I don't think there is universal agreement nowadays (by working probabilists and philosophers of probability) that such a theory is actually *wrong*.